# Trying to identify a function represented by python code

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

I have created a python script to simulate probability of x total n-length arrays having at least 1 True boolean object in them, and the boolean is calculated as probability. the return value is (How many arrays have at least 1 true) / (total amount of arrays)

Here is the script:

```
import random

def rchance(prob):
    return random.random() < prob #T or F

def probo(n, probability = .5):
    total = 1000000 #Higher number increases precision
    final = []
    for i in range(total):
        final.append([rchance(probability) for i2 in range(n)])
    v = [i for i in fin if any(i)]
    return (len(v)/total)
```

I need help generalizing the python function to a mathematical one, but so far I have been able to come up with a function representing probo(x, $\frac{1}{2}$) which is this: $\frac{2^x-1}{2^x}$ for example, probo(2, .5) = 3/4, probo(3, .5) = 7/8, probo(4, .5) = 15/16.

What I am not able to do is generalize this function for any probability.
If this is actually a core combinatorics law, please tell me so I may learn that also.

Edit: I realize now that true generalization would be: probability of x total n-length arrays having at least *p* True boolean objects in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability of getting at least one True is the same as 1 - P(All False). P(All False) = p^n, where p is the probability of True on a single trial. You'll see that the answer you came up with for p=1/2 is equivalent. Look up binomial distribution if you want to know about cases other than at least one True, e.g. at least 2, 3, etc.

Edit: OP corrected me in the comments. P(All False) = (1-p)^n.

Comment: Okay, I understand. I think however that p is (1 - probability of true), since 1-(p^n) for p=.1, n=2 returns .99 while in 1-(1-p)^n returns .19 (as did the script) Thank you so much for the explanation!

Comment: No problem! I defined p that way in my answer, since that's (I believe) the more common way to write it.

Comment: One more question, if you don't mind. is the 1 in 1-P(All false) the 'at least 1 true' part? or would 'at least s true' fit s somewhere into this? Testing leads me to think its 1-(1-p)^(n/s)

Comment: Actually, I messed up above, it is 1-p, you're right. To answer, that won't be quite right. Basically the (1-p)^n is the probability of n False in a row, think coin flipping. But say you're flipping 10 times and you need 2 True. You could look for 1-P(9 or 10 false). But the probability of getting 9 False isn't just the probability of getting 9 False in a row. You could sprinkle the 9 falses in several different ways. Actually, there are 9 ways (10 choose 9). This is why you need the binomial distribution.